# S3 trigger failes to update table in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amazon-dynamodb

I have created a web app in AWS Amplify. A web page uploads a file to an S3 bucket. I have created a trigger that should create a record in DynamoDB for each uploaded file. My trigger code is called, there are no errors I can find anywhere but the table is not updated.

The trigger code:

```
exports.handler = async function (event) {
  console.log('Received S3 event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
  // Get the object from the event and show its content type
  const eventName = event.Records[0].eventName;
  const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name; //eslint-disable-line
  let key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace('%3A', ':');
  const imgSize = event.Records[0].s3.object.size;
  console.log(`Bucket: ${bucket}`, `Key: ${key}`);

  if (eventName === "ObjectCreated:Put") {
    console.log("This is a put event")
    addDBActivity(key);
   }
};

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

function addDBActivity(key) {
  console.log("in addDBActivity");
//  let activityTable = "Activity-***-dev"
  let activityTable = "Activity-ctuqkflvhvbjxftdvdo64xnzle-dev"
  let name = key.split('/').pop();
  let owner = key.split('/')[0];
  let format = "tcx";
  let type = "cycling";
  var params = {
    TableName: activityTable,
    Item: {
      key: { S: key },
      name: { S: name },
      owner: { S: owner },
      format: { S: format },
      type: { S: type },
    }
  };

  console.log(params);

  ddb.putItem(params).promise()
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });

  console.log("after promise");
}
```

schema.graphql

```
type Activity @model @auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner, ownerField: "id" }
  ]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  owner: String!
  key: String!
  format: String!
  type: String!
}
```

After uploading a file this is the log output in CloudWatch:

```
2021-12-18T13:14:26.093+02:00
2021-12-18T11:14:26.092Z    20cf4afe-3c96-4ee2-94c6-7c12c27c4d66    INFO    This is a put event
    2021-12-18T11:14:26.092Z 20cf4afe-3c96-4ee2-94c6-7c12c27c4d66 INFO This is a put event
    2021-12-18T13:14:26.093+02:00
2021-12-18T11:14:26.093Z    20cf4afe-3c96-4ee2-94c6-7c12c27c4d66    INFO    in addDBActivity
    2021-12-18T11:14:26.093Z 20cf4afe-3c96-4ee2-94c6-7c12c27c4d66 INFO in addDBActivity
    2021-12-18T13:14:26.123+02:00
2021-12-18T11:14:26.123Z    20cf4afe-3c96-4ee2-94c6-7c12c27c4d66    INFO    {
  TableName: 'Activity-ctuqkflvhvbjxftdvdo64xnzle-dev',
  Item: {
    key: {
      S: 'public/sourb/ramp_test2tcx-a03e6380-e0c3-4966-b4eb-b74375f930bd.tcx'
    },
    name: { S: 'ramp_test2tcx-a03e6380-e0c3-4966-b4eb-b74375f930bd.tcx' },
    owner: { S: 'public' },
    format: { S: 'tcx' },
    type: { S: 'cycling' }
  }
}
    2021-12-18T11:14:26.123Z 20cf4afe-3c96-4ee2-94c6-7c12c27c4d66 INFO { TableName: 'Activity-ctuqkflvhvbjxftdvdo64xnzle-dev', Item: { key: { S: 'public/sourb/ramp_test2tcx-a03e6380-e0c3-4966-b4eb-b74375f930bd.tcx' }, name: { S: 'ramp_test2tcx-a03e6380-e0c3-4966-b4eb-b74375f930bd.tcx' }, owner: { S: 'public' }, format: { S: 'tcx' }, type: { S: 'cycling' } } }
    2021-12-18T13:14:26.542+02:00
2021-12-18T11:14:26.522Z    20cf4afe-3c96-4ee2-94c6-7c12c27c4d66    INFO    after promise
```

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [async handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async) so your function probably finishes before your database has a chance to get updated. You can wrap your code in a  `Promise` as show in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async) to ensure full execution.